# Prevent Joomla editor from stripping newlines/returns

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5 and have added the text editor to an admin component. When I save the text from the editor, all the newlines/returns are stripped from the text.

I am using a similar SQL call as the following:

```
"UPDATE....... SET body=" .$db->quote(JRequest::getVar('body'))
```

I also tried saving the text without the $db->quote() call without any success.

take care,
lee

Comment: Do not put things into a query without quoting/escaping them. You will be open to SQL injection. Also, which editor are you using? Joomla ships with more than one and there are also third party editors available as plugins.

Comment: From what I understood, using quote() in Joomla does this for me. Is this not true? How do I know what editor is being used?

Comment: Yes, using `$db->quote()` is correct. Don't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem was not the editor, but rather how I was extracting the text with my JRequest::getVar() call. I added JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW to the parameters and the problem is fixed.